# Appium server crashes

Tags: java, appium

I want to start an Appium server, but it crashes, despite having worked fine the last few days.

This code:

```java
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js");
AppiumDriverLocalService service=newAppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(file).withIPAddress("130.127.2.24").usingPort(4723).build();
        service.start(); // error here
```

results in:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.isRunning()" because
> "this.process" is null

It's in the `@BeforeMethod` link precondition.
I had no problem with this code the last 2 days; without any clear reason, it now results in an exception.

I tried to find answers on Youtube and in the documentation, but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the Selenium version to 4.8.1
I had the same problem with version 4.8.2, and downgrading the version works for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the port you are using is already taken?
If you are running in on local machine, maybe your IP changed?
This is how I start service:

```
public static void startService_3(){
AppiumServiceBuilder appiumServiceBuilder=new AppiumServiceBuilder()
        .withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\" + "userName" + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "warn")
        .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SHELL);
service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(appiumServiceBuilder);
service.start();
```

}

I'm using appium nodejs version 1.22.3
ip.appium java client 7.3.0
with selenium 3.141.59

Answer (score 0):

Looks like java client is not compatible with selenium 4.8.2 changes.

Below solution is copied from github issues post:

Solved it by going to $HOME/.m2/repository/io/appium/java-client/8.3.0 and adjusting the file: java-client-8.3.0.pom.
Changing all selenium related dependencies' version tag from: [4.7.0, 5.0) to [4.7.0, 4.8.2) to eliminate incompatible 4.8.2 selenium version.

For more information kindly check this [link](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1872)

code to start appium service:

```
service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(
                new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"))
                        .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
                        .withLogFile(new File("/Users/"+user+"/Documents/logs.txt"))
                        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.USE_DRIVERS, "uiautomator2,xcuitest")
                        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.BASEPATH, "/wd/hub")
                        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOCAL_TIMEZONE)
                        .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                        .usingAnyFreePort()
 );
service.start();
```